# Catalog search always returns "There is not any product available"

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

When I enter a product name in search box and search it then result is always display that : ***There is not any product available***. I have done all configuration of product from admin.

- catalog, search
- in stock
- qty > 0

etc.. all configurations are ok.

Kindly help me how can I solve this?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the search results to help us understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System > configuration > catalog > catalog > catalog search.  Change Search Type to 'Like'
2. Make sure product attributes are searchable.

calatog -> manage attribute -> yourAttribute ->Use In Search Results Layered Navigation ->yes

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reindex category product and search index. System - > Index management